Alarm is not firing in flutter android when phone goes to doze/sleep mode
Alarm is not firing in flutter android when phone goes to doze mode
Using this package. alarm is firing when the phone is active but when the phone is in doze mode/sleep, the alarm is not working.
https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus

Check this link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58263
